# Using nested function finding the second largest number. The function to find the largest number is overriding the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I'm supposed to create a function that returns the second-largest number. I started doing it to run the function to find the largest number. Then I wanted to ommit that largest number from my array and run that same function again. I'm only allowed to use loops. push, pop slice, index, loops and conditions

I've tried switching around where the loops and played around with variables. I tried altering the scope of things. I also contemplated making a new empty array variable, running a loop and pushing all the items that aren't the largest into there then running the largest number function on that array.

```js
var largest = 0;

var findSecondLargest = function(array) {

  for (b = array.length; b > 0; b--)
    largest = findLargest(array); {
    console.log(largest + "largest" + array)
  }
  for (n = array.length; n > 0; n--)
    if (array[n] >= largest)
      array.splice(n, 1);
    else if (array[n] > array[b])
    array.splice(n, 1);
  else if (array[n] < array[b])
    array.splice(-1, 1);
  return array;
};

var findLargest = function(array1) {
  for (x = 0; x <= array1.length; x++) {
    for (j = array1.length; j > 0; j--) {
      if (array1[j] > array1[x])
        array1.splice(x, 1);
      else if (array1[x] > array1[j])
        array1.splice(-1, 1);
    }
  }
  return (array1);
};


findSecondLargest([89, 28, 22, 20, 41, 1, 39, 41, 67]);

findSecondLargest([89, 28, 22, 20, 41, 1, 39, 41, 67]) // returns 67
```

This is what it's supposed to do but it only returns 89. I think it's because the original parameter array gets changed when I try to define the variable "largest".

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is wasteful. We can determine the second largest number using linear space and time -

```js
const secondLargest = (xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( ([ $0, $1 ], x) =>
        x >= $0
          ? [ x, $0 ]
      : x >= $1
          ? [ $0, x ]
      : [ $0, $1 ]
    , [ -Infinity, -Infinity ]
    )
    [1]

console.log(secondLargest([89, 28, 22, 20, 41, 1, 39, 41, 67]))
// 67
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to find the second largest element will work, however, I think you're overcomplicating your code.

The first step is to make a function which will find the *index* of the largest element in your array. You can do this by storing the index of the max element in your array, and loop over all elements inside your array to update this variable:

```js
function getMaxIndex(arr) {
  var max_idx = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var current_elem = arr[i];
    var max_elem = arr[max_idx];
    if(current_elem > max_elem) {
      max_idx = i;
    }
  }
  return max_idx;
}

var nums = [1, 100, 2, -1];
console.log(getMaxIndex(nums)); // 1, because 100 is at index 1
```

Now that you have a method which can retrieve the index of the biggest number in your array, you can remove this number using `.splice(index, 1)`. This will remove the largest number from your array. You can then call `getMaxIndex()` again, with your new array as input, which will again retrieve the index of the biggest element in your passed through array. This index will be the location of the second largest number in your original array:

```js
function getMaxIndex(arr) {
  var max_idx = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var current_elem = arr[i];
    var max_elem = arr[max_idx];
    if(current_elem > max_elem) {
      max_idx = i;
    }
  }
  return max_idx;
}

var nums = [1, 100, 2, -1];
var to_remove_idx = getMaxIndex(nums);
nums.splice(to_remove_idx, 1); // remove the index with the biggest number
var second_largest_idx = getMaxIndex(nums);
var second_largest = nums[second_largest_idx];
console.log(second_largest);
```

You can then encapsulate the logic performed outside your function into a function of its own. You can generalize this so that you can pass a number for the `nth` largest number in your array:

```js
function getMaxIndex(arr) {
  var max_idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var current_elem = arr[i];
    var max_elem = arr[max_idx];
    if (current_elem > max_elem) {
      max_idx = i;
    }
  }
  return max_idx;
}

function getNthLargest(lst, n) {
  var arr = lst.slice(); // copy array (so original passed in array is not modified)
  for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    var to_remove_idx = getMaxIndex(arr);
    arr.splice(to_remove_idx, 1); // remove the index with the biggest number
  }
  
  var n_index = getMaxIndex(arr);
  var result = arr[n_index];
  return result;
}

var nums = [1, 100, 2, -1];
console.log(getNthLargest(nums, 2));
```

**Note**: This approach isn't very efficient. In fact, it would be more efficient to sort the array in descending order and then grab the `nth-1` index. The most efficient approach for something like this is most likely using the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort descending your array and get item at index 1

```js
const arrayNumber = [89, 28, 22, 20, 41, 1, 39, 41, 67];

function findSecondLargestNumber (array) {
  if(!array) return undefined;
  
  return array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a})[1];
}

console.log(findSecondLargestNumber(arrayNumber))
```